# does chase.com login flow use a device unique identifier from javascript?

Tags: javascript, device, uniqueidentifier

chase.com login flow is able to uniquely identify a device and prompt you for an identification code (which can be received via email/text) if the device is a public (not marked as known by the user before) device.

I also tried logging in to a public computer using Chrome and mark it as a known device. The next login on FireFox bypasses the identification code mechanism. So, it's definitely not using cookies.

If chase is doing it using javascript (I'm guessing), I was wondering if someone can shed light on a possible implementation.

Please note that I was using chase.com as an example, not really interested in their implementation specifics.

Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to identify users and devices. Some may include JavaScript, some will rely on it, other don't need it at all. The app in question will combine many ways.

Comment: edited to reflect that I was using chase.com just as an example.

Comment: What is your question then, if it does not refer to chase.com explicitly?

Comment: I think that facebook does this too. I'm interested to hear if anyone knows.

Comment: Bergi, to elaborate further, how do we generate a device unique identifier (of some sort) within the browser that works on all popular browsers? I would like to pass this identifier to the server so that I can recognize the device the next time even if they are using a different browser. That is what chase.com is able to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chase.com login flow is not the same on the iPad. Since iPad does not have flash and after running some more tests on my laptop, I believe chase.com is using a combination of browser cookies and "flash cookies": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object

During my research, I also found out that companies like http://www.bluecava.com/ do "Device fingerprinting" for a cookie-less approach. But, it seems like a solution for targeted ads rather than authentication (I might be wrong).